# three.js Zooming by button click

Tags: html, three.js

I want to add two button for zoom In and zoom Out. How can I do it ?

I try this code but it not working for me

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

 function zoomModel(isZoomOut, scale) {
 if(isZoomOut){
  controls.dollyIn(scale);
 }else{
  controls.dollyOut(scale);
}
} 

$("#clickMe").on("click", function(){
 // call this to make the model larger/ zoom in
 zoomModel(true, 4);

 // call this to make it smaller / zoom out
 //zoomModel(false, 4);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.update();
```

add the code in  zoomModel before end